# iOS App Extensions (Widgets): Open URL, and then execute a method within the app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-extensions

In an iOS App Extension such as [the Today Widget](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html), you can open the application when the widget is selected using [NSExtensionContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSExtensionContext_Class/). Is there any way to execute a method within the application (to move to a different UI view) only after the application is opened via the widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a custom URL scheme which your app will register for and change the view based on the URL.

Example: `myapp://action=showspecialview`

Your app would then be launched and can parse the URL and do the special behavior when it detects `showspecialview` in the URL.